# AngularJS-way: extend controllers/views with notification functionality

Tags: javascript, angularjs, notifications

What is the best way to add common notification functionality to needed controllers in AngularJS?

The goal is to create local notifications that can be easily added/removed for any controller.

So:

1. **Shared functionality** between controllers
2. This functionality should work(?how? don't know) with **view** to output
   notifications

now we have [such solution](http://jsfiddle.net/ujeen/y6K4a/).

```
code there
```

Comment: create a notification service and inject in controller

Comment: it's answer for (1) but what do you propose for (2)

Comment: pls explain more what you want to acheive with some scenario and what type of notification you want to display or send

Comment: updated post with link to our current variant

Answer (score 0):

I like the way implemented in UI Bootstrap (from Angular UI team): http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/alert

```
<div ng-controller="AlertDemoCtrl">
  <alert ng-repeat="alert in alerts" type="alert.type" close="closeAlert($index)">{{alert.msg}}</alert>
  <button class='btn' ng-click="addAlert()">Add Alert</button>
</div>

<script>
function AlertDemoCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.alerts = [
    { type: 'error', msg: 'Oh snap! Change a few things up and try submitting again.' }, 
    { type: 'success', msg: 'Well done! You successfully read this important alert message.' }
  ];

  $scope.addAlert = function() {
    $scope.alerts.push({msg: "Another alert!"});
  };

  $scope.closeAlert = function(index) {
    $scope.alerts.splice(index, 1);
  };    
}
</script>
```

That way, you just add the `<alert>` directive to your view and you're good to go - no need to create shared services or anything like that.

Comment: If you don't want to add the whole UI Bootstrap project dependency, you can at least use the same design and write your own directive.

Comment: AlertDemoCtrl should be rootController otherwise it will not work for another controller, or you will have to duplicate  $scope.alerts and all this functionality to each controller